# A conditionally convergent complex series can be rearranged to be divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I need to prove the following property in general but just don't know how to do it:

Let $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n$ be a series which converges conditionally in $\mathbb{C}$, so it doen't converge absolute. Show that there exists a bijection $\pi : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ so that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_{\pi(n)}$ does not converge.

I know it has something to do with rearrangements of the terms but I don't see how that can solve the problem. I know that if  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n$ converges absolute that after the bijection the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_{\pi(n)}$ also converges, but I don't know if this is useful here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the usual term is “conditionally convergent”

Comment: *Hint:* $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z_n$ is absolute convergent if and only if both $\sum_{n=0}^\infty Re(z_n)$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty Im(z_n)$ are absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, I just noticed that you said $\mathbb{C}$.  However, you can use Martin R's comment that $\sum x_n$ is absolutely convergent iff both $\sum \Re(x_n)$ and $\sum \Im(x_n)$ are absolutely convergent, and proceed as below.

---

**Basic approach.** The series is not absolutely convergent, meaning that the series $\sum y_n$ (with $y_n = |x_n|$) is not convergent.  So divide $x_n$ into its positive terms and its negative terms.  One of the two of those must not converge, because if each of them did converge, the series would have been absolutely convergent.

Thus, put whichever of the two subsets is not convergent first, and that ordering is the one you want.

Comment: You produced a function from the ordinal $2\omega$ not from $\mathbb{N}$. The basic approach is simple but not that much. You need to put many terms from the divergent one until you get a partial sum $>1$, then put one term from the other part, them as many terms from the divergent to get a partial sum $>2$ and then one term from the other one, and so on.

Comment: @noodlesGroup: You're quite right.  That's what I get for trying to work this out on a telecon.  I'll come back to fix this.